# when git clone caffe2 , return thirtparty eigen repository error:

Tags: git, caffe2

when I excuted git clone from caffe2, return thirtparty eigen repository error:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2.git
....
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/RLovelett/eigen.git/' not found

Answer (score 1):

It's a submodule for which the github repo no longer exists.
This caffe2 repo itself seems outdated. As indicated on the front page, [the latest caffe2 source code now lives in the PyTorch repository](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/).